# Eclipse error when installing SDK for Android Wear

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

When I update the SDK i have to update eclipse and all of android stuff disapear, now i can't do any Android project.
Anyone have this problem or know how to resolve it?﻿

There's an image here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dbpk.png

Thanks.

Comment: what problem or error you getting??

Comment: i can't create any android project and i don't have the buttons of Android SDK and VDM

Comment: try to update ADT As well 
Go to eclipse > help > Check for updates.

It should list the latest update of adt. If it is not working try this

go to eclipse > help > Install new software

Click on add

add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Thet is the problem, i do this and later i can't do any android project.

Comment: I resolve the problem reinstalling the ADT Bundle,I don't like this way but i need the IDE to program.